# Move tabs above custom options

Tags: tabs

I'm trying to move my tabs above the custom options but when I edid view.phtml my checkout cart breaks. It's not possible to add anything to the cart [image]

I would like to have the tabs below the small images. We have many custom options so at the bottom off the page if no good for us.

So this should be above the text "Bestelformulier"
[image]

I use a custom theme, so I also add the view.phtml Can somebody help me with this.

```
<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>
<?php $helper = $this->helper('mpanel'); ?>
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
<div class="product-view">
    <div class="product-essential">
        <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if ($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
            <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
            <div class="no-display">
                <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="product-img-box col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="product-shop col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="product-name">
                        <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
                <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
                    <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $this->helper('yotpo')->showBottomline($this, $_product); ?>
            <?php endif; ?> 
                    <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/sku')): ?>
                        <div class="product-sku">
                            <?php echo $this->__('SKU: <span>%s</span>', $_product->getSku()) ?>
                        </div>
                     <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/reviews_summary')): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/alert_urls')): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <div>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('prijsinfo')->toHtml() ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>

                    <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/short_description')): ?>
                        <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()): ?>
                            <div class="short-description">
                                <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>


                    <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()): ?>
                        <div class="add-to-box">
                            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/wishlist_compare')): ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>

                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>

                    <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <div class="add-to-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/brand_image')): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('brand/product_brand')->setTemplate('mgs/brand/product_brand.phtml')->toHtml() ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other'); ?>

                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                    <div class="box-social">
                        <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/email_friend')): ?>
                            <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                                <p class="email-friend pull-left"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/share_this/product')): ?>
                            <div class="social-icons">
                                <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/share_this/span_tags') ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="clearer"></div>
                    <!-- custom statick block 1 -->
                    <div class="static-block-top">
                        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('mgs_panel_product_static_block_top')->setCanEdit(1)->toHtml() ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('staffel_korting')->toHtml() ?>
                <div class="product-shop"><?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="clearer"></div>
        </form>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //<![CDATA[
            var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
            productAddToCartForm.submit = function (button, url) {
                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    var form = this.form;
                    var oldUrl = form.action;

                    if (url) {
                        form.action = url;
                    }
                    var e = null;
                    try {
                        this.form.submit();
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                    this.form.action = oldUrl;
                    if (e) {
                        throw e;
                    }

                    if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                        button.disabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

            productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function (button, url) {
                if (this.validator) {
                    var nv = Validation.methods;
                    delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                    delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                    // Remove custom datetime validators
                    for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                        if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                            delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                        }
                    }

                    if (this.validator.validate()) {
                        if (url) {
                            this.form.action = url;
                        }
                        this.form.submit();
                    }
                    Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
                }
            }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
            //]]>
        </script>
    </div>

    <?php
    $productTabs = $helper->getProductTabs();
    $tabsArray = array();
    foreach ($this->getChildGroup('tabs', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html) {
        $tabsArray[$alias] = $html;
    }
    ?>
    <div id="product_tabs" class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($productTabs as $key => $value): $i++;
                ?>
                <?php if ($key != 'description' && $key != 'additional' && $key != 'reviews' && $key != 'product_tag_list'): ?>                            
                    <li<?php if ($i == 1): ?> class="active"<?php endif ?>>
                        <a href="#<?php echo "box-{$key}" ?>" data-toggle="tab">                                
                            <?php echo Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_tabs/' . $key . '_title'); ?>                                                                               
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php if ($tabsArray[$key] != ''): ?>
                        <li<?php if ($i == 1): ?> class="active"<?php endif ?>>
                            <a href="#<?php echo "box-{$key}" ?>" data-toggle="tab">                                                
                                <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($key, 'title')): ?>
                                    <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>                                                                         
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach ?>
            <?php if ($helper->acceptToUsePanel()): ?>      
                <li>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary popup-link" title="<?php echo $this->__('Manage Product Tabs'); ?>" href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('mpanel/index/manageProductTabs'); ?>">
                        <em class="fa fa-plus"> </em>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <?php
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($productTabs as $key => $value): $i++;
                ?>
                <?php if ($key != 'description' && $key != 'additional' && $key != 'reviews' && $key != 'product_tag_list' && $key != 'product_questions'): ?>   
                    <div class="tab-pane<?php if ($value == 0): ?> active<?php endif ?>" id="<?php echo "box-{$key}" ?>">
                        <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_tabs/' . $key) == 'attribute'): ?>
                            <?php $p = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId()); ?>                            
                            <p><?php echo $p->getResource()->getAttribute(Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_tabs/' . $key . '_attribute_code_value'))->getFrontend()->getValue($p); ?></p>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId(Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_tabs/' . $key . '_identifier_value'))->toHtml(); ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <?php if ($key == 'product_questions'): ?>
                        <div class="tab-pane<?php if ($value == 0): ?> active<?php endif ?>" id="<?php echo "box-{$key}" ?>">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product.questions') ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?php
                        $i = 0;
                        foreach ($this->getChildGroup('tabs', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html): $i++;
                            ?>
                            <?php if ($key == $alias): ?>
                                <div class="tab-pane<?php if ($i == 1): ?> active<?php endif ?>" id="<?php echo "box-{$alias}" ?>">
                                    <?php echo $html; ?>
                                </div>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>                    
                <?php endif; ?>                
            <?php endforeach ?>            
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="product-collateral">
        <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/upsell_products')): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_list_related')->setTemplate('catalog/product/list/related_grid.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>

        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>

    </div>
    <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('mpanel/product_details/brand_products')): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('brand/product_brand')->setData('show_product_short_description', 0)->setTemplate('mgs/brand/related_products.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="clearer"></div>
    <!-- custom statick block 2 -->
    <div class="static-block-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('mgs_panel_product_static_block_bottom')->setCanEdit(1)->toHtml() ?>
    </div>

    <!-- start google rich snippets -->
    <?php if(Mage::getStoreConfig('mgs_theme/general/snippets') == 1): ?>
    <!-- MICRODATA -->
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
      <meta itemprop="name" content="<?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>" />
      <div itemprop="offers" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
        <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="<?php echo $currency_code = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(); ?>">
        <meta itemprop="price" content="<?php echo strip_tags(Mage::helper('core')->currency($_product->getPrice())); ?>">
        <?php
        $microdata_stock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_product)->getIsInStock();
        if ($microdata_stock >= 1){
          $microdata_stock_msg = 'In Stock';
        }else{
          $microdata_stock_msg = 'Out of Stock';
        }
        ?>
        <meta itemprop="availability" content="<?php echo $microdata_stock_msg; ?>">
        <meta itemprop="itemCondition" itemtype="http://schema.org/OfferItemCondition" content="http://schema.org/NewCondition" />
      </div>

    </div>
    <!-- MICRODATA -->
    <?php endif; ?> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to product from admin panel->
select Design tab from Left side. & choose **product info column** from **Display Product Options In**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your commont but thats not what my mean. I would like to have the tabs above the text "Bestelformulier"  I edit my first post with a image.